# Python append line of strings to other line of strings

Tags: python, list, io, concatenation

I'm new in Pyhton so please don't be hard to me. I'm try to get a file called results.txt which should contain strings from two different files. I have a file called:

to-read.txt:

```
api.domain.com
domain.com
www.domain.com
```

and a file called:

to-add.txt:

```
api
www
account
prod
test
temp
```

now I'm try to add for every string in to-read.txt the words from to-add.txt but at the beginning. for example for the api.domain.com then I sould get:

```
api.api.domain.com
www.api.domain.com
account.api.domain.com
prod.api.domain.com
test.api.domain.com
temp.api.domain.com
```

and so on for the other in to-read.txt. My code looks like this:

```
f = open("results.txt", "w")
with open("to-read.txt", "r") as r, open("to-add.txt", "r") as a:

    for read in r:
        data = read.strip()
        print(data)

    for word in a:
        words = word.strip()
        print(words)



f.close()
```

Now I don't know how to append to-add with to-read and save it to results.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
with open("to-read.txt") as domains,\
        open("to-add.txt") as prefixes,\
        open("results.txt", "w") as output:
    for d in domains:
        for p in prefixes:
            output.write(f"{p.strip()}.{d.strip()}\n")

        prefixes.seek(0)
```

The contents of `results.txt` file should look like:

```
api.api.domain.com
www.api.domain.com
account.api.domain.com
prod.api.domain.com
test.api.domain.com
temp.api.domain.com
api.domain.com
www.domain.com
account.domain.com
prod.domain.com
test.domain.com
temp.domain.com
api.www.domain.com
www.www.domain.com
account.www.domain.com
prod.www.domain.com
test.www.domain.com
temp.www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
results=[]

to_read="""api.domain.com
domain.com
www.domain.com"""

to_add="""api
www
account
prod
test
temp"""

to_add = to_add.split("\n")
to_read= to_read.split("\n")

for domain in to_read:
    for prefix in to_add:
        results.append(prefix+"."+domain)

print(results)
```

This just iterates through the lists, adds them together, and puts the resulting domains in the list results.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a good starting point - you just need to create 2 loops, one which iterates over the prefixes (from `to_add` file`) and another, inner loop, which iterates over the`domains`for each`prefix` and concatenate them.

Try this:

```
with open("to-read.txt", "r") as r, open("to-add.txt", "r") as a, open("results.txt", "w") as f:
    domains = r.read().splitlines()
    prefixes = a.read().splitlines()
    for p in prefixes:
        for d in domains:
            f.write(f"{p}.{d}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use (and need to replace `to_read` and `to_add` with the file contents):

```
to_read = """api.domain.com
domain.com
www.domain.com"""

to_add = """api
www
account
prod
test
temp"""

result = ["{}.{}".format(prefix, domain)
          for domain in to_read.split("\n")
          for prefix in to_add.split("\n")]

print(result)
```

This yields

```
['api.api.domain.com', 'www.api.domain.com', 'account.api.domain.com', 'prod.api.domain.com', 'test.api.domain.com', 'temp.api.domain.com', 'api.domain.com', 'www.domain.com', 'account.domain.com', 'prod.domain.com', 'test.domain.com', 'temp.domain.com', 'api.www.domain.com', 'www.www.domain.com', 'account.www.domain.com', 'prod.www.domain.com', 'test.www.domain.com', 'temp.www.domain.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("to-read.txt", "r") as r, \
     open("to-add.txt", "r") as a, \
     open("results.txt", "w") as f:
  data = [ x.strip() for x in r ]
  words = [ x.strip() for x in a ]
  for domain in data:
    for word in words:
      f.write("{}.{}\n".format(word, domain))
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('read.txt', 'r')
read = f.readlines()
print(read)

f2 = open('add.txt', 'r')
add = f2.readlines()
print(add)
result = []
count = 0
for i in add:
    i = i.strip()
    for j in read:
        j = j.strip()
        result.append(i + '.' + j + '\n')
        count += 1
f3 = open('result.txt', 'w')
f3.writelines(result)
f3.close()
```

result.txt:

```
api.api.domain.com
api.domain.com
api.www.domain.com
www.api.domain.com
www.domain.com
www.www.domain.com
account.api.domain.com
account.domain.com
account.www.domain.com
prod.api.domain.com
prod.domain.com
prod.www.domain.com
test.api.domain.com
test.domain.com
test.www.domain.com
temp.api.domain.com
temp.domain.com
temp.www.domain.com
```